# How to get the data sent by ajax with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Code in my `a.php` file:**

```
<?php include ('b.php'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nf(info){
    $.ajax({            
        type:'POST',
        url:'a.php',
        data:'getinfo=' + info         
    }); 
}
}
</script>
<?php
$info = $_POST['getinfo'];

if($info=="1"){
    $_SESSION['ses1']=1;
}else{
    $_SESSION['ses1']=2;
}
?>
<a onclick="nf(1)">Option1</a> || <a onclick="nf(2)">Option2</a>
```

When change `$_SESSION['ses1']` makes some changes in `b.php` file. But I can't retrieve the data?

Comment: Please redo you last sentence, I can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: What's in `b.php` file? What do you want to get? Which data?

Comment: You are probably not calling `session_start()`

Comment: i think you have an error on your sintax, check data:{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you got it all wrong:

- start session with `session_start()`;
- correct your function, it has one `}` extra;
- move your post up to access same file.
- I don't know what `b.php` includes but you need jQuery library too

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['getinfo'])){
        $info = $_POST['getinfo'];
        if($info == 1){
            $_SESSION['ses1'] = 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['ses1'] = 2;
        }
        die;
    }
?>
<?php include ('b.php'); ?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nf(info){
    $.ajax({            
        type:'POST',
        url:'a.php',
        data:'getinfo=' + info         
    });
}
</script>

<a onclick="nf(1)">Option1</a> || <a onclick="nf(2)">Option2</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

**First of all**

```
function nf(info){
    $.ajax({            
        type:'POST',
        url:'a.php',
        data:'getinfo=' + info         
    }); 
}
} // ?
```

You have one bracket `}` too many.

**Set data**

The correct way to set the data is by a json string like this:

```
function nf(info){
    $.ajax({            
        type:'POST',
        url:'a.php',
        data:{getinfo:info}        
    }); 
}
```

**Retrieve data**

```
function nf(info){
    $.ajax({            
        type:'POST',
        url:'a.php',
        data:{getinfo:info}        
    }).done(function(data){
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        //data is now an array with all the data you echod in the a.php which is json encoded
    }); 
}
```

**Please have a look at:**

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: thank for answer but now working with data:'info='+info is it wrong?

Comment: @Kevinkevin I'm not 100% sure if it is wrong, but have a look at the jQuery documentation. They use a json encoded array, so you might want to consider using that instead. Because then you are sure you are working by the "rules"